# Oracle client runs into timeout

Tags: oracle10g, timeout

We are using an Oracle DB with different clients to view/edit the tables. It seems that the clients disconnect after a very short amount of time of inactivity (maybe 5 minutes).

DreamCoder and Navicat Lite (our preferred Windows clients) both do not offer any option to solve this problem. When a timeout occurs I have to close the connection which means that I have to close all tables, queries and so on within the clients. That is so frustrating so I wonder how I would be able to prolong the time span for a timeout? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most recent version of Navicat now offers an option to send a "keepalive" to the database which finally solves my problem.